# Redactor - doesn't generate unordered list

Tags: redactor

I'm using Redactor v2.8.5. it doesn't render an unordered list in HTML? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Redactor is perfectly capable of rendering an unordered list, so perhaps your question is a little unclear.

If you mean that there's no formatting button to format an unordered list, check that you're using an appropriate redactor config which allows the use of 'unorderedlist' in your field definition:

[image: Redactor config options]

More instructions about how to configure Redactor in Craft can be found at https://github.com/craftcms/redactor

Comment: I'm able to see these buttons on the editor. And I'm able to see bullet points with my content in the editor. But when I see that same page on website, I don't see the bullet points

Comment: Then this is sounding like a CSS issue, rather than Redactor. If the markup that's generated correctly has `<ul><li></li></ul>` tags, it's most likely your stylesheet that's changing the formatting.